# how to resolve "Flows stopped due to missing node types. Check logs for details." Error in Node Red?

Tags: node-red, node-redis

whenever I deploy the project it shows this Error, I have tried restarting the server, PC but nothing helped.

Comment: The Node-RED log will tell you which nodes are missing. Edit the question to include the output from when Node-RED starts.

Comment: Do not forget to check configuration nodes also

Answer (score 0):

I ended up backing up each flow then deleting each flow to see the problem is really from "missing nodes". I deleted all flows and did not resolve the problem.
I restarted and rebooted Raspberry Pi in between.
Finally, I updated and upgraded the linux system then updated the nodered:

```
 update-nodejs-and-nodered
```

Here is the status:

```
    8:11 mqtt Node-RED[295]: 29 Mar 13:28:11 - [warn] [node-shri-dashboar
Mar 29 13:28:11 mqtt Node-RED[295]: 29 Mar 13:28:11 - [warn] [node-shri-dashboar
Mar 29 13:28:11 mqtt Node-RED[295]: 29 Mar 13:28:11 - [warn] -------------------
Mar 29 13:28:11 mqtt Node-RED[295]: 29 Mar 13:28:11 - [info] Settings file  : /h
Mar 29 13:28:11 mqtt Node-RED[295]: 29 Mar 13:28:11 - [info] User directory : /h
Mar 29 13:28:11 mqtt Node-RED[295]: 29 Mar 13:28:11 - [warn] Projects disabled :
Mar 29 13:28:11 mqtt Node-RED[295]: 29 Mar 13:28:11 - [info] Flows file     : /h
Mar 29 13:28:11 mqtt Node-RED[295]: 29 Mar 13:28:11 - [info] Server now running 
Mar 29 13:28:11 mqtt Node-RED[295]: 29 Mar 13:28:11 - [info] Starting flows
Mar 29 13:28:11 mqtt Node-RED[295]: 29 Mar 13:28:11 - [info] Started flows
```

The NodeRed is running...

Comment: This does not answer the question

Answer (score 0):

Two ways you can do this: (1) a package manager like NPM or Yarn OR (2) the Node-Red Pallette Manager.

To start, it is best to search for the nodes that the error says you are missing in the [flow library](https://flows.nodered.org/). This should give you an idea of the packages that you are missing/need to install.

**Package Manager**

You need to install the proper nodes wherever you are deploying. Typically, this is done via npm, but you can also use yarn.

For each, you just need to run the install command that will install the missing package and add it to the package.json file that should already exist in your Node-Red project. Notes on how to do that can be found in [NPM docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-install) and [Yarn docs](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/add/).

**Pallette Manager**

You can also do the installation via the Pallette Manager if you are unfamiliar with package managers or don't have the ability to use one. Info on how to do this can be found in the Node-Red [docs](https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/editor/palette/manager#installing-nodes).